# mysql replace method plus java

Tags: java, mysql

i knew how to replace a single value all over the field by using REPLACE method like

```
   UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, `string`, `anothervalue`)
```

but what if i have to replace different values by different other things in the same field e.g
"," is to replace by "." and "/" is to replace by white space " " and "hons" is to replace by "honours" in the same field, can i do it in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You can cascade the `replace`

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `field` = replace(replace(replace(`field`, ',', '.'), '/', ' '), 'hons', 'honours')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `field` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'/',' ') ',','.') , 'hons', 'honours')
```